# How many ways are there to train the players?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

$210$ players participated the summer course.How many ways are there to choose a trainer out of $20$ trainers for each player so that every trainer have to train different number of people?

**My attempt**:If the trainers had to have at least one player to train then we would have at least $1+2+ \dots +20$ players which is equal to $210$ so the answer would be $\frac{210!}{20!19! \dots 1!}$ but the problem is that a trainer can have no players to train so we will have at least $190$ players and we have to check every case which is really hard.Any hints?

This question is in chapter "combination" of the book so I am looking for a proof using combination more than others.But others are acceptable too.

Comment: But each player has to have a trainer, right? And the only way to do that with each trainer having a different number of trainees is a trainer with 1, a trainer with 2, ..., a trainer with 20, right?

Comment: @GerryMyerson No trainer number $20$ can have $21$ players and the first trainer can have non.

Comment: Yes, you're right – and there are other possibilities, e.g., $0+1+\dots+18+39=210$.

Comment: This is partitions with distinct parts and 2 specific sizes (20 and 19), corresponding to no 0s and one 0.

Comment: @ArtimisFowl So what is the answer?

Comment: Lots of hand computation, enumeration, a lookup table, or a computer program. It's tedious enough I don't want to bother. There could be something clever in this case, but partitions are generally messy, and nothing pops out.

Comment: I suspect that you are expected to assume each trainer has at least one client, so your answer is the expected one.  The mess that is hiding in Christian Blattner's last paragraph supports this.

Comment: @RossMillikan I don't think so.Then it would become a really easy combination problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Denote by $x_i$ $(1\leq i\leq20)$ the number of participants that trainer$_i$ is taking care of. Then there are nonnegative integers $y_i$ such that
$$x_1=y_1,\quad x_2=x_1+1+y_2,\quad x_3=x_2+1+y_3,\quad \ldots\ ,$$
so that
$$x_k=k-1+\sum_{j=1}^k y_j\qquad(1\leq k\leq20)\ .$$
Now we want
$$210=\sum_{k=1}^{20} x_k=190 +\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^k y_j\ ,$$
which can be rewritten as
$$\sum_{j=1}^{20}(21-j)y_j=20\ .\tag{1}$$
Let  $z_l:=y_{21-l}$ $(1\leq l\leq20)$. Then $(1)$ amounts to
$$\sum_{l=1}^{20} l\>z_l=20\ .\tag{2}$$
We need the number of solutions of $(2)$ in  integers $z_l\geq0$. Each vector $(z_1,z_2,\ldots, z_{20})$ satisfying $(2)$ encodes a partition of $20$, whereby $z_l$ denotes the number of parts of size $l$. It follows that the number of such vectors is equal to the number of these partitions, which is $627$, according to Abramowitz & Stegun. Multiply this with $20!$ to assign the different trainers to the different workloads. But we have not yet taken care of the 210 different personalities that have to be trained. This would mean setting up a multinomial coefficient for each of the $627$ admissible workload schemes.

Answer (score 1):

We can solve the basic question - where every trainer has at least one person to train - in two steps. Imagine a bag of $210$ balls of different colours, with a different number of each colour. The players each take a ball. Now the different ways that can happen are given by the appropriate [multinomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Multinomial_coefficients)
$$\frac{210!}{20!\cdot 19!\cdot 18!\cdots 3!\cdot 2!\cdot 1!} = \frac{210!}{\prod_{k=1}^{20}k!}$$

Then we can allocate the colours to trainers in a second drawing, which can happen in $20!$ ways. This is multiplied in to give $$ \frac{210!\cdot 20!}{\prod_{k=1}^{20}k!}= \frac{210!}{\prod_{k=1}^{19}k!}$$

There are many ways to partition 210 into twenty different numbers if we allow a trainer to have zero trainees. We can consult a(20) for [OEIS A000041](https://oeis.org/A000041/list) to get $627$ options - one of which we have already covered above. [This is the count of different multisets of integers that sum to $20$ - which we would then add on to a "preload" of $19,18,\ldots,1,0$ in the different partitions to get the distinct sums required.] Each of these would require similar treatment to above.